# OpenCL matrix reduction in two stages

Tags: algorithm, opencl

I have a 2d array of *M* x *N* entries.

```
A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 ... AN
B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 ... BN
...
```

I want to reduce this array to a single value in two stages.

Stage 1: Calculate function values for each item in a row, and sum them with some weights.

```
A = W0*f(A0) + W1*f(A1) + W2*f(A2) + ...
B = W0*f(B0) + W1*f(B1) + W2*f(B2) + ...
```

Stage 2: Compare results to an input vector and calculate a chi-square value.

```
CHI_SQ = (A - X)^2/SX^2 + (B - Y)^2/SY^2 + ...
```

I am trying to do this in parallel using OpenCL. However, I have a hard time figuring out the best strategy for this kind of algorithm. For example, there are many examples out there that would loop over the matrix rows, and many sources that state you should not do this. Could someone be so kind as to outline how this problem can be solved optimally?

Comment: Do you have to calculate a lot of 2D matrixes, or just one big 2D matrix? That will define how to structurize your code

Comment: Good question, DarkZeros. I have to calculate one matrix, 10.000 - 100.000 rows with 50 - 100 columns, in one pass. Then I do some host stuff (no way around it) and, after some time, come back and calculate another matrix. So, for all intents and purposes, I have just one matrix to calculate in one go.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest to use 2 kernels. The first kernel will perform 1 workgroup per row, calculate with each work item an operation `W0*f(A0)`, and accumulate locally, and output to a global array.The second kernel would compute the CHI_SQ (you can also reduce using workgroups at this stage), giving you a 100 values that you can finalize on the CPU in a fast for loop. Later I will write a propper answer to this.

Comment: AMD did a great case study on different reduction strategies, you should have a look : http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/

Comment: Thanks @WarfarA for the suggestion. After reading the linked document, it is a bit clearer why certain codes run faster than others. Still, I would like to know how ideally one can apply the theory in this particular situation. You will notice that this is not a simple reduction, because the intermediate results enter as a square into the computation, i.e. they must be know fully at this point.